# dynatable JS to generate table from json data dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, dynatable

Hello i need help in generating fully dynamic table using **[dynatable.js](https://www.dynatable.com/#json-from-ajax)** or any other js suggestions welcome as well.  **here are some other** [Jquery Tables](https://www.sitepoint.com/12-amazing-jquery-tables/)

currently i am using php script to call API and save cURL response into .Json file

sample of **local.json** is below after calling API from PHP

```
[
  {
    "adapterid": 44835,
    "rowid": 1573784208932,
    "battery": 3610,
    "createddate": "15-11-2019",
    "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
    "id": 2277491836402479600,
    "projectid": 32107,
    "rssi": -90,
    "temp": 25.75
  },
  {
    "adapterid": 44835,
    "rowid": 1573784212032,
    "battery": 3660,
    "createddate": "15-11-2019",
    "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
    "id": 2277491836402479600,
    "projectid": 32107,
    "rssi": -89,
    "temp": 25.75
  },
  {
    "adapterid": 44835,
    "rowid": 1573784215034,
    "battery": 3610,
    "createddate": "15-11-2019",
    "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
    "id": 2277491836402479600,
    "projectid": 32107,
    "rssi": -96,
    "temp": 25.75
  }
]
```

now i want to use this data into well formed table which allow to **search** and **pagination** so i found **dynatable** useful but i am having difficulties to convert fully dynamic table because i need to mention table header every time when data change or new column added into json data

```
<thead>
    <th>adapterid</th>
    <th>rowid</th>
    <th>battery</th>
    <th>createddate</th>
    <th>gid</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>projectid</th>
    <th>rssi</th>
    <th>temp</th>
</thead>
```

My full page code to generate dynatable. it's working for me but i don't want to create th element by myself i want code to do that for me and generate dynatable

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Dynatable Demo</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alfajango/jquery-dynatable/master/jquery.dynatable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/alfajango/jquery-dynatable/master/jquery.dynatable.js"></script>
</head>


<body id="page-top" >   

<table id="my-table" class="table dataTable my-0">
<thead>
    <th>adapterid</th>
    <th>rowid</th>
    <th>battery</th>
    <th>createddate</th>
    <th>gid</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>projectid</th>
    <th>rssi</th>
    <th>temp</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>


<script>
$.getJSON('local.json', function (response) {     
  $('#my-table').dynatable({
  dataset: {
    records: response
  },
});
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

can someone help me to generate fully dynamic table with search and pagination

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Zinggrid](https://www.zinggrid.com/). It's pretty easy to use and their documentation is straightforward.
To generate the table from JSON, you can use the *zing-grid* tag.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.zinggrid.com/zinggrid.min.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<zing-grid caption="Sample Table"
    data=[
  {
    "adapterid": 44835,
    "rowid": 1573784208932,
    "battery": 3610,
    "createddate": "15-11-2019",
    "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
    "id": 2277491836402479600,
    "projectid": 32107,
    "rssi": -90,
    "temp": 25.75
  },
  {
    "adapterid": 44835,
    "rowid": 1573784212032,
    "battery": 3660,
    "createddate": "15-11-2019",
    "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
    "id": 2277491836402479600,
    "projectid": 32107,
    "rssi": -89,
    "temp": 25.75
  },
  {
    "adapterid": 44835,
    "rowid": 1573784215034,
    "battery": 3610,
    "createddate": "15-11-2019",
    "gid": "01:f0:50:11:a1:35:87",
    "id": 2277491836402479600,
    "projectid": 32107,
    "rssi": -96,
    "temp": 25.75
  }
]>
</zing-grid>
</body>
</html>
```

This should do. As for [search](https://www.zinggrid.com/docs/features/search) and [pagination](https://www.zinggrid.com/docs/features/paging), it's included in the website.